# WordPress plugin caching issues

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cookies

I'm trying to set and read cookies within WordPress across my site by way of a custom plugin that I wrote.

`add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_cookie_code' );`

The code that I wrote works, however, once it's deployed to our live server it does not.

I think this is because of our WordPress caching system. When I turn it off, my cookie code works but once it's on, it does not.

Without turning off my WordPress caching system, how can I get my code to work with it?

I want each page to be cached by the caching system but I still want my little bit of code to be executed.

Thanks

Comment: I'm hosted at WPEngine. I'm not sure what they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is an issue with the WPEngine caching system.

When I switched my code from being PHP based to JavaScript, I was able to solve the problem that I was having.

More information on this issue can be found here:
[Cookies and php sessions on WPEngine](https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//Try this code in function.php file

//set cookie 
add_action( 'init', 'setCookie' );
function setCookie() {
setcookie( 'my-name', 'my-value', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN   );
}

//get Cookie 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'getCookie' );
function getCookie() {
$cookie_val = isset( $_COOKIE['my-name'] ) ? $_COOKIE['my-name'] : 'not set';
}

//Delete / Unset Cookie
add_action( 'init', 'unsetCookie' );
function unsetCookie() {
setcookie( 'my-name', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
?>
```

Comment: My code is very similar to what you have written. 
1) I'm calling it from a custom plugin and not the function.php file
2) I'm not creating a Javascript alert. 
The issue seems to be with the caching system. Or do you think I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact WPE support and have them exclude those cookies specifically from Varnish caching on your install.
Staging is uncached which would be why it works there.

Comment: As far as I know, excluding cookies from the varnish caching system won't work. According to this WPEngine post, it's better to manipulate cookies through Javascript instead of PHP - https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/